# Loading select options using service in constants file in the dynamic form creation in angular

Tags: angular

I am creating dynamic forms. The field creation I have done in the constants.ts file. When creating the drop-down field I want to load options values from the service. How to do that? And I need to load that fields using the ng container in HTML. When I am trying to load in `components.ts` file using `element.options` I am getting an `undefined error`. How can we do this?

Comment: Hello, please provide some code, something you have already tried. Otherwise this question will be closed pretty soon.

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz example?

Comment: If(element.hasOwnProperty(‘options’)&&element.type===‘select’){element.options=this.user service.getdata(element.drop down) I am using this. But options undefined is coming